# Obtaining a Transformed Matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, transformation

I have a matrix
$$m = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 
1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
4 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where the rows represent judges and columns represent persons ranked.
There are three transformation rules -

1. For $j<i$; place in the $(i,j)$ cell the observed rank of the person expected to be ranked j-th by the i-th judge
2. For i = j; $(i,j) = 0$
3. For $j>i$; place in the $(i,j)$
   cell the observed rank of the person expected to be ranked j - 1.

the transformed matrix is:

$$T = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 
1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

I think I may be misinterpreting this transformation - for example - 
in $m$ for $i=5$ and $j=1$ we have $i>j$ so the rule says to place in the $(i,j)$-th cell which would be $(5,1)$, the observed rank of the person expected to be ranked $j-th$ by the $i-th$ judge so this would be entry $m(5,1) = 4$ but $T(5,1) = 2$.

I am simply trying to reproduce this example in this paper  - page 6-7
http://www.statpt.com/correlation/lewis_johnson_1971.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you missed the footnote: “transformed according to Homans’ hypothesis” - for example - in $m$ for $i=5$ and $j=1$ we have $i>j$ so the rule says to place in the $(i,j)$-th cell which would be $(5,1)$, the observed rank of the person expected to be ranked $j$-th by the $i$-th judge, that is of  the person expected to be ranked $1$-th by the $5$-th judge, so, *according to Homans’ hypothesis*, this is the $4$-th person which has the observed rank $2$ by $5$-th judge, so this would be entry $m(5,1)=2=T(5,1)$.